# How to validate personal email with json schema

Tags: json, schema

The problem is i don't know how to validate personal email with Json Schema, what is the pattern for this ?

example@outlook.com

I already tried looking in google but cant find anything.

```
    "email": {
        "description": "Email of the user",
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "",
    },
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use **format** to validate email in JSON Schema.

```
 "email": {
    "description": "Email of the user",
    "type": "string",
    "format": "email"
}
```

Comment: Documentation for reference: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#built-in-formats

Answer (score 10):

You could use:

- The spec's built in format validation  `"format": "email"` https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#built-in-formats
- However if your tool/library doesn't recognize the spec's built in format validation, then regular expression: "^\S+@\S+\.\S+$" would make sure it contains the expected characters. Still invalid values of domains and TLDs can be entered.
- Use the the min (and optionally max length), the min length of 6 characters means that you can't make email shorter than this: `a@b.de`. The max length provides some sanity against abysmally long emails (127 characters for a email should be enough)

```
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "title": "Email address",
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+$",
          "format": "email",
          "minLength": 6,
          "maxLength": 127
        }
      }
```